# drop part of string in awk after specified symbol

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a field like this:

```
"1427842735.300406","fp":
```

This is a timestamp and some obsolete info.
I need to extract timestamp before the dot.

I don't want to do like below because the timestamp probably could consist from  a different amount of digits:

```
awk '{print substr($4, 2, 10)}'
```

So I want to take it from the 2-nd symbol till dot. Should I use match() for that as a last arg to find index? If so - could you please provide an example.

Or there is an easiest way to do so?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo '"1427842735.300406","fpu":' | awk -F'[".]' '{print $2}'
1427842735
```